# What is good practice for managing contributing classes for Eclipse RCP Parts

Tags: java, annotations, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm just wondering what is good practice when it comes to managing the contributing `Class` of a `Part` in Eclipse RCP development? I know that when a `Part` get's focus in the application it calls the `Class` that is linked to that `Part`, and in that `Class` you can use annotations such as `@PostContruct` and `@Focus` to indicate certain behaviours.

What I'm wondering is whether I should be destroying the `Class` and re-loading it every time the user switches `Parts`? Is it bad practice if I don't or is there no need to destroy a `Class` and re-load it every time?

Answer (score 1):

The DI framework will control the life cycle of your contribution Class for you and will call the annotated methods as is appropriate. So you don't need to destroy it manually.

Have a look at this tutorial explaining the annotations for Parts:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#programmingmodel_annotation

Comment: I see! Thanks for the explanation. I had been following the Vogella tutorials but it wasn't 100% clear to me from them :)